# Need help to use curl coding

Tags: php

I am creating a academic/community site in Joomla . One of my site requirement is to obtain the result from the official college site . I will be creating a module on my site which will have college id as input and on submission it will show the result obtained from the official website .

I am finding it difficult to pass the data from one site to other . The official website is using Post method for college id input .
Information :  official website = http://results.vtu.ac.in/
  and the input is 1kn04cs066 the name of field is "rid"

I have tried the sample code given by Alec but i am not getting the result page.

Please help me with detailed approach with programming code sample . It will be highly appreciated . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need at least the following options to perform the request and get the result: CURLOPT_POST, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS and CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER. But there could be more options you need to perform the request.

```
    if(!($request = curl_init('http://results.vtu.ac.in')))
        die('curl_init failed');

    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('rid' => '1kn04cs066'));

    if(!($result = curl_exec($request)))
        die('curl_exec failed with error: '.curl_error($request));

    curl_close($request);

    echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks. But its not working i am getting the submission page only as a result. Kindly help.

Comment: After some testing I quickly discovered it requires the value of the button as well to get the right page. So add another pair to the array in the order of 'submit' => 'SUBMIT' and it will work. You can use firefox with the web-developer toolbar to easily inspect form parameters.

Answer (score 0):

BTW that would be

```
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('rid' => '1kn04cs066','submit' => 'SUBMIT'));
```

Not

```
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('rid' => '1kn04cs066'));
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('submit' => 'SUBMIT'));
```